# Modify source HTML in Xamarin WebView (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: android, html, dom, xamarin.android, android-webview

I know it's not fashionable to use Visual Studio to create Android apps, but I prefer it.  Still, if I need to use Android Studio I can.

My app loads a webpage in a WebView.  This part works.  Now I need to access the DOM.  I'm trying to implement tabbing through the links and inputs on a webpage.

My thought is I can get the list of links (and input boxes), modify the html to set a border around the first one.  When the tab or arrow keys are pressed, I can restore the first one, and put a box around the next.

My issue is that if I try to load the html into something first (like agile html parser or HtmlSource), it doesn't show up in the WebView.  And if I show it directly in the Webview I can see it perfectly, but I cannot access the Html.

- I miss the old Windows WebBrowser control that let you load a page and gave you access to the DOM.  Anything like that out there?

Comment: You can accept it as an answer. This may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try using EvaluateJavaScriptAsync:

```
var result = await mywebview.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.title");
```

Also change the HTML code in the html variable and the changes will be reflected in the WebView

```
WebView mywebview = new WebView();
string html = "<html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>";
HtmlWebViewSource htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = html;
mywebview.BindingContext = htmlSource;
```